# Use the theory of residue to evaluate $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\cos(3\theta)d\theta}{5-4\cos(\theta)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, residue-calculus

**My attempt:**

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\cos(3\theta)d\theta}{5-4\cos(\theta)}$$

I know I can substitute $\cos (\theta)$=$\frac{e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}}{2}=\frac{1}{2}(z+\frac{1}{z})$, but I'm stuck on figuring out how to do the same thing to $\cos(3\theta)$.

Comment: You can use multiple angle formula.

Comment: See example 12 in this link http://mathfaculty.fullerton.edu/mathews/c2003/IntegralsTrigMod.html   The only difference is that there is $2\theta$ instead of $3\theta$ but the principle remains the same